# Javascript function clearInterval does not stop animation

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I am  rotating an element when I click on  a button  using `setInterval` along with `clearInterval` to stop rotation when a certain value is `reached`  by clearing the `interval time t`.It works well but when I click on the same button over and over again before the current animation completes , **the animation no longer stop rotating**.`clearInterval` does not work in this case.

The code below illustrates it :

```js
var t; // interval 
var x = 0 ; // counter
var cal ; // element to be rotate

function prepareRotatesX(){
    x=x+5;
    cal =document.getElementById("myCalendar");
    cal.style.transform="rotateX("+x+"deg)";
    
    if(x>360){ clearInterval(t); x=0;}
}

function rotate(){
   
    t = setInterval(function(){ 
      prepareRotatesX();
    }, 10);
}
```

```css
#myCalendar{ 
                position: absolute;
                top:45px;
                left:20px;
                border: 2px solid blue;
                width: 210px;
                height:170px;
                background-color:blue;
            }
```

```html
<div id="myCalendar">
     <!---HERE COME CALENDAR -->
 </div>
 <!-- make rotation-->
 <button id='bnext' onclick='rotate();'>Rotation</button>
```

So how to stop  rotation in this case ?

Comment: Call `clearInterval` when you're clicking on the button if `t` is defined.

Comment: Because you overwrite t and the first one still is running. So logic says to stop the original or if it is already running, do not run it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option you are probably after is if it is still running than do not run it again. So see if t is defined, if it is exit. And when the loop is done, than you can reset the interval.

```js
var t; // interval 
var x = 0; // counter
var cal; // element to be rotate

function prepareRotatesX() {
  x = x + 5;
  cal = document.getElementById("myCalendar");
  cal.style.transform = "rotateX(" + x + "deg)";

  if (x > 360) {
    clearInterval(t);
    x = 0;
    t = null
  }
}

function rotate() {
  if (t) return;  // if t is defined, than it is running so exit
  t = setInterval(function() {
    prepareRotatesX();
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
#myCalendar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 210px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCalendar">
  <!---HERE COME CALENDAR -->
</div>
<!-- make rotation-->
<button id='bnext' onclick='rotate();'>Rotation</button>
```

other option is to just clear the interval and restart it

```
function rotate() {
  if (t) clearInterval(t)
  t = setInterval(function() {
    prepareRotatesX();
  }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `t` declared globally is creating problem, if you move `t` to local scope in your code. It should fix your problem (Assuming that previous clicks rotation should continue)

In case if you want to abort the previous click, you can follow solution given by @epascarello

```js
var x = 0 ; // counter
var cal ; // element to be rotate

function prepareRotatesX(t){
    x=x+5;
    cal =document.getElementById("myCalendar");
    cal.style.transform="rotateX("+x+"deg)";
    
    if(x>360){ clearInterval(t); x=0;}
}

function rotate(){
   var t; // interval 
    t = setInterval(function(){ 
      prepareRotatesX(t);
    }, 10);
}
```

```css
#myCalendar{ 
                position: absolute;
                top:45px;
                left:20px;
                border: 2px solid blue;
                width: 210px;
                height:170px;
                background-color:blue;
            }
```

```html
   <div id="myCalendar">
     <!---HERE COME CALENDAR -->
 </div>
 <!-- make rotation-->
 <button id='bnext' onclick='rotate();'>Rotation</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your rotate method, which is called on click you need to make a change to see if the interval is defined and clear it if it is. See below code update.

```js
var t; // interval 
var x = 0 ; // counter
var cal ; // element to be rotate

function prepareRotatesX(){
    x=x+5;
    cal =document.getElementById("myCalendar");
    cal.style.transform="rotateX("+x+"deg)";
    
    if(x>360){ clearInterval(t); x=0;}
}

function rotate(){
    if(t !== undefined) {
        clearInterval(t);
    }
    t = setInterval(function(){ 
      prepareRotatesX();
    }, 10);
}
```

```css
#myCalendar{ 
                position: absolute;
                top:45px;
                left:20px;
                border: 2px solid blue;
                width: 210px;
                height:170px;
                background-color:blue;
            }
```

```html
<div id="myCalendar">
     <!---HERE COME CALENDAR -->
 </div>
 <!-- make rotation-->
 <button id='bnext' onclick='rotate();'>Rotation</button>
```